# Is there a way to perform event tracing in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

I am testing my website and we encountered some issue that we cannot replicate constantly.
Is there any function we can use in the browser to see a list of event triggered, and what user entered to trace the error?

Thanks in advance
Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the console you can usefully monitor events with the monitorEvents API. The API takes an object to be monitored and then an event to listen for.

Example:

```
monitorEvents(window,"click");
```

Output in MS Edge beta (Chromium):

[image]

Reference:

[Monitor Events](https://blittle.github.io/chrome-dev-tools/console/monitor-events.html)

It will work with MS Edge (Chromium) and Google Chrome browser. For Firefox you can try to check Firebug extension.